# Creating LDAP directory users with specific attrs for Dovecot email server

Tags: ldap, dovecot

I have openldap-2.4.39-8.el6.x86_64 installed into my CentOS release 6.4 (Final) machine. I have another machine which I installed dovecot, and I would like to perform ldap authentication for my dovecot mail users. This is what my ldapsearch result currently looks like:

```
dn: dc=mailtest,dc=example,dc=net
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: Test-Dovecot Lab, Inc.
dc: mailtest


dn: ou=People,dc=mailtest,dc=example,dc=net
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: People
```

This is how I configured my dovecot-ldap.conf.ext file:

```
user_attrs = \
  =user=%{ldap:mailRoutingAddress}, \
  =quota_rule=*:storage=%{ldap:messageQuotaHard}k

user_filter = (mailRoutingAddress=%u)


pass_attrs = \
  =user=%{ldap:mailRoutingAddress}, \
  =password=%{ldap:userPassword}, \
  =userdb_quota_rule=*:storage=%{ldap:messageQuotaHard}k


pass_filter = (mailRoutingAddress=%u)

iterate_attrs = mailRoutingAddress=user

iterate_filter = (objectClass=messageStoreRecipient)
```

I would like to add users into ldap directory with the following attributes included if possible:

```
mailRoutingAddress
userPassword
mailRoutingHost or mailHost
messageQuotaHard
```

Can someone help me how to do this?